ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pycryptodome)
I am trying to install Pyrebase to my NewLoginApp Project using PyCharm IDE and Python. I checked and upgraded the version of the software and I selected the project as my interpreter, but I still get this error:
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pycryptodome)

Below is the screenshot of the error that I am getting:

Below is the whole code I wrote to the terminal to fix the problem:



I'm not sure what the problem here is. Your screenshots don't really help much either.

Note that the latest release of Pyrebase was in 2017, seven years ago. There's a high chance it won't work that well with modern Pythons.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Please, show us text, not screenshots of text! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly format it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

I think you should install Pyrebase4
pip install Pyrebase4

or
pip3 install Pyrebase4

https://pypi.org/project/Pyrebase4/

A simple python wrapper for the Firebase API with current deps

This is a more recent one with last released on Apr 30, 2024



The old one was :
pip install Pyrebase

it was last released on Jan 7, 2017 so it will not be supported by new python versions.
https://pypi.org/project/Pyrebase/

I'm studying CS50 and had the same error message whilst trying to install the required pip install flask_session so I can call from flask_session import Session in my code. I installed pyrebase but it still didn't let me install flask_session. I believe you need msgspec to install flask_session, but reading through the documentation, the current msgspec isn't compatible with the latest python release however the engineering development release is, which I've linked below.
pip install git+https://github.com/jcrist/msgspec.git
Then the
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects
Error message I get trying to install flask_session disappears!

Hi @Tempo, I think your workaround would be more helpful if you explain why it's needed ... i.e. in this case it's a requirement but it;'s not clear why.  Thank you for contributing and I look forward to you improving the post, best regards.

Apologies, I'm new to this. Hopefully that's better!

It is better, nice work.

Usually this kind of errors are related to the use of an obsolete "setuptools" python dependency. Try upgrade the "setuptools" dependency in your virtual environment
pip install setuptools --upgrade

